# How to work with two more drop down Dynamic in VBA and webelement or selectelement?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

Im working with selenium and vba in these days, and i have doubt; when i try to work with drop-down "dynamics" i cant understand why my webelement or selecelement dont refresh or get error when drop-down refresh.

For example i have to work with a webpage that have a table and two select and a Button like input, table change only when i have selected a option in both select.

for this exmaple we will say:

firts select have id Select1.
second select have id Select2.
table table have id Table_1.
button input have id button1.

Table1 change or refresh only when Select1 AND Select2 have a option selected (if only one have a option selected Table doesnot  change or refresh)

At the beginning when open webpage (webdriver) Select1 and select2 dont have option select (you know  ...   "Select a option"), of course table_1 have anything

for this i use:

```
Sub example()

'*// here a put code to initialize web driver and named WEB3

'*// in this part i have webpage opnened so...


'*//here i get my variables

Set GGT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select1").AsSelect
Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect
Set SubElement = WEB3.FindElementByClass("button1")

'*//use this for to "play" with webpage

For Each i In GGT.Options
   for each j in CBT.Options
    GGT.SelectByIndex (i.Attribute("index"))
    CBT.SelectByIndex (j.Attribute("index"))
    subelment.click
Next
Next

end sub
```

well, in this point table depends of two select;

Select1 and Select2 are independent and both are statics, i mean, options always are same

Subelment (button) refresh table and both select to beginning (dont refresh webpage).

if i run code i dont have any problem Select1 take option(1) then Select2 take its option(1), (2), etc; you know all combinations and table generate all tables.
but if transform Select2 and now select2 is dependent on Select1, i have next condition:

Select1 is static;Select2 is dinamic and dependes on select1, thats to say, suppose that Select1 have 3 options fruits, shapes and colors.
but Select2 changes for each option in Select2 for this exampple 
if Select1 is fruits select2 have options apple and pears; if Select1 is shapes select2 have options square and circle and if select1 is color select2 show red and blue.

here is where i have a problem i dont understand what happen that generate error

```
For Each i In GGT.Options
For Each j In CBT.Options
    GGT.SelectByIndex (i.Attribute("index"))
    CBT.SelectByIndex (j.Attribute("index")) '*//here show error 10 in 
                                                 second iteration
    subelement.click
Next
Next
```

firts i tought that because Select2 change i have to refresh variable CBT so added:
    Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect 
between fors so...

```
For Each i In GGT.Options
Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect
  For Each j In CBT.Options
    GGT.SelectByIndex (i.Attribute("index"))
    CBT.SelectByIndex (j.Attribute("index")) '*//here show error 10 in 
                                                 second iteration
    subelement.click
  Next
Next
```

but does not work error still, i dont know why if i refresh CBT dont refresh it.
I mean is like in Excel when in cells(1,1) put =C2+F3 if i move cells F3 to r2 automatic actualize funtion so "=C2 +r2" but if i use key supr or delet only change value that get funtion (0), BUT if i right click on F3 and select eliminate cell generate a error REF because cells F3 was eliminate and put a new F3 I think this it was happen for that reason i added 
     Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect
to get new Select2 but is not work.
CBT sitll get old select2 and dont get new select2

after i tried to use explicit code, thats to say, dont use variables CBT, GGT and put all sentences but still same.

SO thast is mi question; how to use SET or refresh a Webelement o Selectelement insdie FOR-FOR with Drop-Down.

or a explication why dont refresh variable like other variables, i mean
this work

```
Dim L as integer
L=4
L=5
L=L+5
```

this work

```
SET H=Webdriver.findelementbyid("kgkj")
SET H=Webdriver.findelementbyid("utut")
SET H=H.asselect
```

But if i put it inside a FOR-FOR (i am sorry the habit FOR-FOR is two nested for's or a FOR inside FOR XD) it does not work

Someone that can explainme why or how to do work that little example with FOR-FOR and drop-down dynamic.

firts of all, thanks

NT: i use .asselect and findelmentbyid() because time ago a used to use getelment and Select, but now i don't know why that syntaxis no still work (i think is because use VBA)

Comment: Do you have an example url we can use  for reproducing this behaviour please?

Answer (score 0):

Should your ordering be different? If 2 changes dependent on 1 then selections on 1 I would expect to happen before setting 2 and looping over 2.

```
For Each i In GGT.Options
    GGT.SelectByIndex i.Attribute("index") 
    'possible wait condition here
    Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect
    For Each j In CBT.Options       
       CBT.SelectByIndex j.Attribute("index") 
       subelement.click
    Next
Next
```

Comment: ..... (no delete, no suprimir ,no change position) and that cell is referended by other cell tha have a funtion (example; "=Cells(1,1)+Cell(2,2)") it get a error #ref because cell have cease to exist this is what happen when i put inside FOR-FOR.

Comment: yeah i use that form and does not work, the problem is with first set CBT inside FOR work , but when GGT actualiza el Select1 with option(2). selected; select2 change (because is dynnamic) in this moment CBT get error buecause make reference to select2 that does not exits because Select1, changed it,  and when i try to refresh CBT with other SET CBT and get new Select2 it dioes not, still with Select2(old ) and get error 10 "Referece to an objet that dont exist in page" i try to explain with a example  in excel when you eliminte a cell

Comment: You mean the id changes?  What does it change to?  Sounds like you need to match the two dropdowns by a position or something that remains common across selections.

Comment: Nop, ID not change, it is for that reason that i dont undestand what happen,  Ok Objet "Select1" and "Select2" dont change, the chenge is for "Options" that contains Select", i mean Object Select has ID Select1 and have predefined Options that option dont changes; For select2 first only have the option default (thats to say, nothing) when select1 "select" 1 (option(1).selected= true) this do that select2 get new options (i put a example up) so get option (1),(2), etc. and it work, but when Select1 option (2) select2 refresh its options and get new options but conserve its id only change option

Comment: Without a webpage to use I'm not sure what else to say. I would expect the above answer to logically be the way to handle this. I would expect a wait condition before Set CBT = WEB3.FindElementById("Select2").AsSelect to esnure new options have populated. Have you tried adding a wait before this line?

Comment: i think something happeneds inside loop because when i do it with  only sentences and dont use FOR i dont have a problem, but imagine that if options are 100 for each select i never finish it. i had read many examples and guides but say anything about this problem why inside loop CBT using SET not refresh , i mean in this everioment you can use one variable many times, put it diferents values, like G=4 then G= 5, then G=G +8 but in simples words, i put G=5 then i put G=8; H= G+2 but and the end G=7 because no get G=8 and conserve G=5.So what happnen with object selecelemnet that do error 10

Comment: and yes a use doevents, wait, sleep, and do not work and qhen debugger popup it focus me in    CBT.SelectByIndex (j.Attribute("index"))    and  error say error 10 Reference to an object that dont exist in page" thats mean that when ussing your help code